# Overloading std::sqrt

Tags: c++, overloading, sqrt

I've tried to overload `std::sqrt` from `<cmath>` like this:

```
class MyClass {
    ...
}

MyClass std::sqrt(const MyClass& arg) {
    ...
}
```

But it failes with error
`namespace "std" has no member "sqrt"`.

I'm using MS c++ compiler with Visual Studio

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Except for a few extension points, you are not allowed to add stuff to the `std` namespace.

Comment: I think you're looking for an explanation of Argument Dependent Lookup: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
namespace std {
    MyClass sqrt(const MyClass& arg) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not allowed to add something like this to `std`.

Comment: @ArtTemiy This might appear to work, but it is undefined behavior. Don't do this.

Comment: As already pointed out this is UB. See [extending std anmespace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std)